# Pass booleans in AJAX

Tags: xml, ajax

I'm trying to pass boolean variables from the server to the client in AJAX. I found this solution on stackoverflow:

> You want to distinguish between "real"
>   booleans and the texts "true" and
>   "false"?
>
> Well - an attribute might help you -
>   e.g. IsActive.
>
> For "text":
>
> ```
> <problem>false</problem>
> ```
>
> For booleans:
>
> `<problem IsActive="false"></problem>`

Now my question is simple: how do I read back the IsActive attribute in javascript?
I'd imagine it would be something along the lines of:

```
var problem = xmlResponse.getElementsByTagName("problem")[0];
var IsActive = problem.getAttribute("IsActive");
```

but what's the exact code for getting that to work?

Much obliged.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using XML, use what's called a [boolean attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/common-microsyntaxes.html#boolean-attributes), true is when the attribute exists, and false is when it doesn't exist. I assume you're not using any JS libs like jQuery or prototype.

You can then simply use the [hasAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.hasAttribute) method on the dom node:

**XML**

```
<problem IsActive>foo</problem>
-or-
<problem IsActive="IsActive">foo</problem>
```

**JS**

```
var problem = xmlResponse.getElementsByTagName('problem')[0];
var IsActive = problem.hasAttribute('IsActive');
```

AFAIK most "AJAX" these days uses JSON, which makes data passing significantly easier.

Comment: Thanks for your help! The first method you suggested generates an parse error, "Specification mandate value for attribute", the second doesn't. DO you know why this is?

Comment: in HTML it's ok to not have a value for an attribute. For true xml, you *must* have a value for an attribute.